# BLE (BluetoothGatt) Calling disconnect again and again after connect one time

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on Android BLE application.
I am facing an issue:- when app trying to connect ble device `BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED` is calling everytime.
It connecting 1 time in 5,6 attempts of connection, once connected it will call `BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED` next 4,5 times.
I am closing the connection GATT connection on disconnect.
Here is code for disconnect

```
public void disconnect() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
}

/**
 * After using a given BLE device, the app must call this method to ensure
 * resources are released properly.
 */

public void close() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.close();
    mBluetoothGatt = null;
}
```

and I am calling these methods in :

```
else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            disconnect();
            close();
            Utility.dismissProgress();


            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
            intent.putExtra("DISCONNECTED_DEVICE_ADDRESS", gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }.
```

I need that everytime it should call connect.

Comment: Please leave @Mike's edit in place, it was a good one (add reasonable formatting, fix spelling, trim begging).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Which AN device you are using?

```
if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            if (status!=133&&status!=62||disconnectCount>=2) { /*If more then 2 count gatt close process*/
                disconnectCount=0;
                setConnected(false);
                intentAction = MyUtils.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                if (getmBluetoothGatt() != null)
                    refreshDeviceCache(mBluetoothGatt);
                getmBluetoothGatt().close();
                setmBluetoothGatt(null);

            }else { /*reconnection goes here*/
                disconnectCount++;
                if (isConnected) {
                    disconnectDevice();
                }
                connectDevice(mDevice);
            }
         }
```

Try this it may help..

Comment: I am using Nexus 5,Samsung S7,Nexus 6.I have tested on more than 7 devices from 6.0 to 8.0 Android OS

Comment: can you please post full code of these methods.I need this urgent